# Volley request with multiple resources

Tags: android, json, adapter, android-volley

I have a problem to display data from multiple resources by using volley.

Parts of this JSON-Response of the tracks should be displayed in a ListView:
 
`{"tracks":[{"owner":"2","idtrack":"6","start":"2014-02-06 21:52:07","end":null,"name":"Track987"},{"owner":"1","idtrack":"10","start":"2014-02-19 20:38:44","end":null,"name":"TestTrack4"},{"owner":"2","idtrack":"13","start":"2014-03-19 20:58:57","end":null,"name":"Ttt54"},{"owner":"1","idtrack":"15","start":"2014-06-04 09:59:35","end":null,"name":"Test"}]}`

But that's not my problem.
I do this by an adapter.

In every row of my ListView the name and the starttime are displayed. For Example:

- Track987
- Thu Feb 06 21:52:07 MEZ 2014

So far so good.
Now, I also want to display the owner. But I have only the id of an user in my JSON-Response. I want to display the owner name.
I can get the name  by an other JSON-Request:
 `{"iduser":"2","email":"sl@email.com","lastname":"Lastname","firstname":"Firstname}`

What is the best way to solve my problem that one row looks like this:

- Track987
- Thu Feb 06 21:52:07 MEZ 2014
- Firstname Lastname

At the moment when all tracks are loaded by volley and i notify the adapter, the information about the owner aren't present. So I get a NullPointerException from my CustomAdapter.

Which solution would be the best?

Comment: Better pass the lastname and firstname of the owner with the first json

Comment: If you can't add the `firstname` and `lastname` nodes into the first `json response` then you could check in your `Adapter` if the `Firstname` and `Lastname` fields are empty. If they are, kick off a new `Http request` and fetch the `Firstname` and `Lastname` for the given row. So lazyloading the values so to speak.

Comment: OK, in this case I could add the name in the first response.